# What does " Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 " mean?

Tags: python, pip

I keep getting an error when I try to install some basic python libraries like `BeautifulSoup`. The error looks like this:

[image: error screenshot]

What exactly does that mean, and how do I fix it? I already tried these commands:

```
pip install --upgrade
pip install
pip install unroll
```

As it was suggested in other posts, but this didn't seem to help either..

Comment: Looks like there's some python 2.7 code in the install script, because there are no parentheses in the print statement.

Comment: Can you try with the -H parameter for sudo as suggested in the warning message ?

Comment: I thought the -H parameter only changes that the sudo command can only change things in the home directory instead of from root, because otherwise someone might be able to install malicious code somewhere. Am I wrong?
Also, still getting the same error even with -H

Comment: Does noone know how to solve this? I'm relatively new to linux and programming and this is really discouraging to be honest, I'm failing when I haven't even gotten started...

Comment: Same issue, on Ubuntu 16.04 with Python 2.7.12. This post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/python-pip-install-gives-command-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-c) has a bunch of answers but none of them work

Comment: @Matifou how did you try to install it? I just tested on a fresh set up 16.04.3 VM and it works perfectly (besides the install wants sudo to function)

Comment: @Videonauth sorry should have mentioned my problem is about unroll/rpy2! Tried to install with `pip install unroll`, or `pip install rpy2==2.2.7`, both fail with same error message as in post above. (and indeed BeautifulSoup works with sudo). None of `pip install --upgrade setuptools`, `pip install ez_setup` or `easy_install -U setuptools` did help. Any idea? Thaaaanks!

Comment: You can try to use the Python3 version and download it with Pip3

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what's too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `sudo which python pip | xargs -rd '\n' readlink -f`, `sudo python --version` and `sudo pip --version`? (`sudo` may be relevant here because `root` may have a different `PATH`.) Thanks.

Comment: @Matifou What does `pip --version` report?

Comment: Thanks @DavidFoerster. I'm not the original author of post (should have maybe started another post... but thought was same issue, sorry) . Here is the output: `sudo which python pip | xargs -rd '\n' readlink -f` gives */usr/bin/python2.7* and */usr/local/bin/pip*.  `sudo python --version` gives *Python 2.7.12* and `sudo pip --version` leads to
*pip 9.0.1 from /home/matifou/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)*. See also output below user.dz post for pip versions. Overall errorinstalling is *Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 *

Comment: @Matifou: Your Python/Pip executables and library paths are completely messed up. Please open a new question and include as much information about your various Python and Pip installations as possible. Thanks.

Comment: So @DavidFoerster, it seems my issue is slightly different than the one here, so I opened a new post here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/975523/pipinstall-gives-command-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-1, but happy to award here the bounty if it works (seems not possible to move a bounty)!  Thanks!

Comment: So I started a new bounty at https://askubuntu.com/questions/975523/pipinstall-gives-command-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-1, happy to have your feedback @DavidFoerster, thanks!

Comment: Hi @DavidFoerster, was wondering whether you had any hints on the "messed-up paths" in the new post https://askubuntu.com/questions/975523/pipinstall-gives-command-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-1?noredirect=1#comment1570565_975523? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The syntax error `Missing parenthesis...` clearly shows you have a python3 interpreter trying to execute python2 code.  I do not know where you read the installation instructions for 'BeautifulSoup' but according to the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-beautiful-soup), you have two different packages, one for python2 and the other one for python3.
They are installed respectively:

```
$ apt-get install python-bs4 (for Python 2)

$ apt-get install python3-bs4 (for Python 3)
```

It is also possible to use pip but the recommended package is beautifulsoup4.  As a footnote, they state '*The BeautifulSoup package is probably not what you want. That’s the **previous** major release*'.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This is confusing but actually I posted the bounty for an issue I believed was the same as package BeautifulSoup, and is actually not  (about unroll and rpy2), so opened a new post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/975523/pipinstall-gives-command-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-1 thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Force python2 version of `pip`:

```
sudo pip2 install BeautifulSoup
```

You may have a custom setup for `pip` which could be pointing to `pip3`. So how did you install `pip`? Could you check & add to the question output of:

```
ls -l $(which pip); dpkg -S /usr/bin/pip
```

Comment: Sorry it's a  little confusing, my question is actually about package `rpy2` and `unroll`, which produce also same error code (while beautiful soup can be solved by sudo) . Using pip2 leads to same error: `pip2 install rpy2==2.2.7`:  *Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1*. I get running your code: *-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 204 Oct  2 10:14 /usr/local/bin/pip
python-pip: /usr/bin/pip*. Thanks!

Comment: @Matifou From that output, you can see that you have another copy of `pip`  in `/usr/local/`. Try again with full path `/usr/bin/pip2 install rpy2`

Comment: Mmh, unfortunately this doesn't help either, still same error message... But indeed, I was 2 pip, with two versions: `/usr/bin/pip2 --version`
*pip 8.1.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)*
`pip2 --version`
*pip 9.0.1 from /home/matifou/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)* (and wasn't able to auto-upgrade the /usr/bin/pip2 one). Thanks!

Comment: So it seems my issue is slightly different than the one here, so I opened a new post here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/975523/pipinstall-gives-command-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-1, but happy to award here the bounty if it works (seems not possible to move a bounty)!  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You are installing the wrong package. BeutifulSoup is version 3.2.1 and back from 2012. You want beautifulsoup4.

Also, instead of using `pip` you can just use `apt`. The package name is `python-bs4`.

The text in orange suggests that you messed up your installs by mixing and matching using `sudo` and not using `sudo` and possibly using `--user`.

Also, is your pip version up to date? `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: Hi. My question was actyually about rpy2 and unroll, and thought it was the same issue while it is not. So I posted a new one: https://askubuntu.com/questions/975523/pipinstall-gives-command-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-1 But I gave you the bounty as I think you are hinting to the right issue, of having mixed up the python install. Hopefully you will get a hint to solve my issue? Thanks!