# Installing spiconfig and egg_info on Ubuntu 16.04 + Python 3.8

Tags: 16.04, python3, docker

I'm trying to get a Docker image up and running with Ubuntu 16.04 and Python 3.8 so I can build [ROS2 Foxy](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Releases/Release-Foxy-Fitzroy/), but I have a couple of problems with their modules, specifically with [`qt_gui_cpp`](https://github.com/ros-visualization/qt_gui_core/tree/foxy-devel/qt_gui_cpp):

```
--- stderr: qt_gui_cpp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/share/python_qt_binding/cmake/sip_configure.py", line 9, in <module>
    import sipconfig
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sipconfig'
make[2]: *** [sip/qt_gui_cpp_sip/Makefile] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/qt_gui_cpp_sip/CMakeFiles/libqt_gui_cpp_sip.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
---
Failed   <<< qt_gui_cpp [14.7s, exited with code 2]
```

And:

```
--- stderr: test2to3
usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help

error: invalid command 'egg_info'
---
Failed   <<< test2to3 [0.54s, exited with code 1]
```

In my various attempts, I've tried obvious stuff like this to install from scratch:

```
ENV NEW_PYTHON_BASE_VERSION=3.8
ENV NEW_PYTHON_VERSION=${NEW_PYTHON_BASE_VERSION}.0
RUN curl -L https://www.python.org/ftp/python/${NEW_PYTHON_VERSION}/Python-${NEW_PYTHON_VERSION}.tgz | \
  tar xz && \
  cd Python-${NEW_PYTHON_VERSION} && \
  ./configure --enable-optimizations && \
  make altinstall && \
  rm -rf Python-${NEW_PYTHON_VERSION}
RUN pip3 install -U setuptools sip ez_setup
```

But nothing seems to work. The answers for [this similar question](https://askubuntu.com/q/881687/189361) don't work for me either. Any suggestions as to where I should look?

Comment: ROS2 Foxy supports Ubuntu 20.04 (https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Releases/Release-Foxy-Fitzroy/#supported-platforms) , Could you add 16.04 is required? You may think of it like rolling-back 4years of code changes.

Comment: @user.dz I know that, but theoretically it should build as-is, as long as I can add the requisite libraries. I don't think it does any particular OS trickery that would tie it to a specific version.

Comment: Where did you reach in these instructions (https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Foxy/Linux-Development-Setup/)  without error? Could you upload the complete log of the step that fails to https://paste.ubuntu.com , add link to the question.

Comment: I can't follow these instructions as I need, for instance, to install Python 3.7 and newer cmake and git over the 16.04 versions. For now I've set the make to skip over the failing modules, and hope that nothing critical depends on them...

Comment: Would you check sip for Python3.8 as in this issue report: https://github.com/ros2/ros2/issues/660#issue-413536920 . It is ok at least full build long, partial output just may mislead us.